# Visual Studio WSDL create async/await SOAP webservice

Tags: c#, web-services, soap, async-await

I've got a SOAP webservice in my C# winforms application, but I'm trying to get WSDL.exe to generate with Task-Based async/await methods.

I've read up on the documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/netframework-4.0/7h3ystb6(v=vs.100)) and tried adding the following XML file into the `par` switch but its still not giving me the awaitable Task based methods for calling the webservice methods asynchronously.

```
// BEGIN WSDLPARAMETERS.XML

<wsdlParameters  xmlns="http://microsoft.com/webReference/">
  <webReferenceOptions>
    <verbose>false</verbose>
    <codeGenerationOptions>properties newAsync enableDataBinding</codeGenerationOptions>
  </webReferenceOptions>
</wsdlParameters>

// END WSDLPARAMETERS.XML

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community>wsdl.exe  "http://********/interchangeservices.asmx" /out:"****\WebServices.cs" /l:CS  /n:"AdelaideInterchangeAutomation" /par:"*****\wsdlparameters.xml"
```

this returns methods like this

```
    /// <remarks/>

    public AwaitingUpload CheckHistoryNotUploaded() {
        object[] results = this.Invoke("CheckHistoryNotUploaded", new object[0]);
        return ((AwaitingUpload)(results[0]));
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public void CheckHistoryNotUploadedAsync() {
        this.CheckHistoryNotUploadedAsync(null);
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public void CheckHistoryNotUploadedAsync(object userState) {
        if ((this.CheckHistoryNotUploadedOperationCompleted == null)) {
            this.CheckHistoryNotUploadedOperationCompleted = new System.Threading.SendOrPostCallback(this.OnCheckHistoryNotUploadedOperationCompleted);
        }
        this.InvokeAsync("CheckHistoryNotUploaded", new object[0], this.CheckHistoryNotUploadedOperationCompleted, userState);
    }

    private void OnCheckHistoryNotUploadedOperationCompleted(object arg) {
        if ((this.CheckHistoryNotUploadedCompleted != null)) {
            System.Web.Services.Protocols.InvokeCompletedEventArgs invokeArgs = ((System.Web.Services.Protocols.InvokeCompletedEventArgs)(arg));
            this.CheckHistoryNotUploadedCompleted(this, new CheckHistoryNotUploadedCompletedEventArgs(invokeArgs.Results, invokeArgs.Error, invokeArgs.Cancelled, invokeArgs.UserState));
        }
    }
```

but ideally I would like it to return Task-Based async methods so i can call them with the `await` keyword.

```
    public AwaitingUpload CheckHistoryNotUploaded() {
        object[] results = this.Invoke("CheckHistoryNotUploaded", new object[0]);
        return ((AwaitingUpload)(results[0]));
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public async Task<AwaitingUpload> CheckHistoryNotUploadedAsync() {
        await .....
    }
```

Comment: And what are you getting? Have you tried to set `verbose` to `true`?

Comment: @PauloMorgado I have updated the question, please check it. And yes I have tried setting `verbose` to both `true` and `false`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to solve this by creating the file via `Add Connected Service` in Visual Studio.

Under the `Advanced` menu there is an option to generate task based asynchronous methods.

[image]